# Display an image in ionic

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

First of all, i get this error when i make the request.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:9848:51)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3722:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:71849:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3721:60)
at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3499:47)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3796:34)
at invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:4934:14)
at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:4971:21)
```

I can see the image I want when I click on network tab. This is my request.

```
let head= new HttpHeaders;
    head.append('reid', id);
    head.append('responseType', 'image');

    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getimg', {headers: head}).subscribe(result => {
        this.data = result;
        console.log("was : " ,id);
        console.log(this.data);
        }, error => console.error(error));
```

The next thing is that I want to do is that I want to display the image in the details.page.html. How can I do this?

Comment: I suggest u to return file image from api with get request and write url to img source directly in src tag. other way u need to trust the source before u give it to src tag

Comment: I returned an image from backend. How do I display it in Ionic

Comment: Just put it to src tag of image attribute                <img src="https://example/Controller/Action?id={{id}}"  class="user-img">  such this example